# Generate a coverage path given a polygon region

Tags: uav, path-planning, coverage

I'm making an app which controls a drone (DJI) and takes photos.
In one particular feature, the user can draw a polygon (let's keep it a convex quadrilateral for now) and the app should generate a serpentine path for the drone to fly over the entire region.

[image: Example from DJI GS Pro app]

Input: 4 vertices of the polygon

Output: Array of coordinates of the path.

Any heads up on which algorithm to use? 
I've looked in to Boustrophedon Cell Decomposition, but there's not much documentation on it.

Comment: Hi @Ramsundar Shandilya, did you ever manage to complete this? I don't see an accepted answer. Which language did you use to generate your coverage path to the serpantine line. I am looking for examples on how to do exactly this in preferably python, C# or SQL... My search on the internet is not really producing any tangible example on how to achieve this

Answer (score 3):

This thing is generally called **coverage path planning**.

If you are particularly interested in Boustrophedon Cell Decomposition, you may have a look at the paper introducing it: [Choset and Pignon (1998)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d94b/903d3cffa239bfa7ea5c64b6ee1e7f73f5e8.pdf).

You may also want to check out [this survey paper](http://dugi-doc.udg.edu:8080/bitstream/handle/10256/9088/Survey-coverage-path-planning.pdf?sequence=1).

Comment: Thanks @PetchPuttichai. The survey paper was really useful. Do you have recommendations as to which approach to use, given the input I have is in Cartesian coordinates? Thanks

Comment: I'm not very familiar with coverage path planning (I mainly work on motion planning) so I can't give you any recommendation. However, if the problem is as you stated where the area is convex, using a basic exact algorithm like Boustrophedon Cell Decomposition will do just fine. Using fancier algorithms will likely not make big differences and probably cause you more time to implement.